# Use IN comparison in MySql with group_concat

Tags: mysql

I [followed this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) and wrote this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID IN table2);
```

> Output : It just selects only the first row but where as

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (1,2);
```

> Output: selects two rows

These are the exact queries which I am using

```
mysql> show create table tmp_product_ids;
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table           | Create Table                                                                                                                                   |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tmp_product_ids | CREATE TABLE `tmp_product_ids` (
  `product__id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order__id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tmp_product_ids;
+-------------+-----------+
| product__id | order__id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         2 |
|           2 |         1 |
+-------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from tmp_product_ids where product__id in (1,2);
+-------------+-----------+
| product__id | order__id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         2 |
|           2 |         1 |
+-------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select group_concat(product__id) from tmp_product_ids;
+---------------------------+
| group_concat(product__id) |
+---------------------------+
| 1,2                       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tmp_product_ids where product__id in (select group_concat(product__id) from tmp_product_ids);
+-------------+-----------+
| product__id | order__id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         2 |
+-------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can any one explain this behaviour ? 
and how can i write mysql query for deleting rows `delete from table1 where ID in (select ID from table2)` without using joins ? 
NOTE:
I have used group_concat function to get the ids from different table:

Comment: Why not use a join? Joins are absolutely the best and right way to handle this situation.

Comment: Also: I can't reproduce your first results. The output from `select * from table1 where ID in (select ID in table2);` should give all records in Table1 where the ID exists in table2.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I cannot use joins as these two tables are not connected in any way, I want to delete the rows in table1 using IDs which I get from table2 using group_concat function

Comment: any one out there to solve my problem ?

Comment: Why are you doing `where product__id in (select group_concat(product__id) from tmp_product_ids)`? The `group_concat()` is your problem. Try `where product__id in (select product__id from tmp_product_ids)`

Comment: It doesn't matter that the tables are not connected. You can still write a JOIN query.

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ I am using "select group_concat(product__id) from tmp_produt_ids" as the actual ids are stored in another table in as comma separated values

Comment: The `tmp_product_ids` does not have comma separated values, as far as we can see. Which table are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a quick explanation.

So you are saying `DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE ID IN (SubQuery);`

WHatever will be selected in `subquery`, and having same `ID`  as `ID` in `Table_1` will be deleted.

Before deleting you can execute the `subquery` separately. and you'll come to know how many rows is selected and how many rows are matching to `Table_1`.

You can also put a `WHERE` condition in your `subquery`.

`DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID From Table_2 WHERE Name = 'John');`

And if You are writing `IN` clause then it is like this for `strings`

`WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3');`

OR

In case of `INT`

`WHERE ID IN (1,2,3);`

Answer (score 0):

You IN statement is a little off. Since you have it written like:

```
WHERE ... IN ('2,1')
```

The Query is looking for the litteral string ['2,1']. You need to enclose each in ticks:

```
WHERE ... IN ('2','1')
```

Or if this is an integer field just:

```
WHERE ... IN (2,1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the result of the select 'select ID in table2' ?

Answer (score 0):

The results from your first two queries depend on the data in the tables. Your last two queries just return a boolean, you ask

> is 1 a component of {2, 1}?

The result is 1 (true). If you ask

> is 1 a component of {'1, 2'}?

it correctly returns 0 (false).

The warning you get is probably because you are comparing integer values with a string. See also Wes's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i write mysql query for deleting rows

You can write a simple join query like

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Without `JOIN` you can as well go with your subquery

```
delete from table1 
where ID in (select distinct ID from table2);
```

You can as well use `WHERE EXISTS` like

```
delete from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 where id = t1.id);
```

Again, your first query `select * from table1 where ID in (select ID in table2);` returns 1 row cause most probably `table2` has only 1 record.

Do a `select count(*) from table2` to verify the same.